# Google chrome - Copy image and pasting in word document is not working

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

Tried pasting images into word document from asp.net .aspx page using Google chrome - Copy image functionality . It displays blank image.

It works fine with IE browser.

Also, pasting image in msPaint works fine.

P.S. copying image using Google chrome - right click 'Copy image' from any other website (e.g. www.google.com) and pasting in word doc works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and use this workaround, which is annoying, but for now it works.

I copy the image in Chrome and paste the image into a paint program, paint.net, and then copy the image from paint.net and paste it into Word.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be because Word tries pasting it in HTML Format.

To avoid this, do the following:

1. In the Home tab, click the arrow under "Paste" and click Paste Special
   [image]
2. Choose "Picture (PNG)" and click OK
   [image]